# Which site should I ask this math question on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a fairly specific math problem that I want to ask, but I am not sure where I should ask this question.

The question is basically: How do I find out, using a mathematics formula, if the digit in the 10's place in a number is even or odd?

I need to know this as part of a computer programming problem, but the answer to the question seems to be also a mathematical one.

This isn't hard math, so I'm afraid it would be poorly received on Mathematics.SE.

It has the structure of a riddle, but I don't know the answer so I don't think that the Riddles.SE would be good either.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: If you intend to attempt this with pure math then go ahead and post it in Mathematics.se. If you're looking for code that will solve this for you, codeGolf might be your best shot.

Comment: If you have an attempt at a solution that you can't get working, this would probably be just fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Given this is a programming problem, stackoverflow seems like the right place for me.

Answer (score 8):

From the Math.SE [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about:
>   •Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems
>   •Hints on mathematical problems (but please read our FAQ about homework questions)
>   •History and development of mathematics (see also: History of Science and Math)
>   •**Solving mathematical puzzles**
>   •Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site)

This would seem to be on topic on Math.SE.

---

I would also be remiss to not point out that [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) has questions such as [Creating a solved 9x9 Sudoku based on certain rules](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/10600/2322) where the person is asking for help solving a puzzle related problem.

Puzzling.SE also has MathJax enabled and can deal with the deeper math questions of puzzling too.

See also [Is it appropriate to pose a puzzle where I don't know the answer?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930/2322) from their meta.

All that said, I'm not active on Puzzling.SE (nor Math.SE) and just going from what is available in the help center and on their meta site.

Answer (score 1):

> This isn't hard math, so I'm afraid it would be poorly received on Mathematics.se

Mathematics.SE seems to not be your best choice here. It is about professional math here so not a good choice. I'm pretty sure it really only accepts high-school and up mathematics there so you're right about being poorly received on that site.

> I need to know this as part of a computer programming problem, but the answer to the question seems to be also a mathematical one... It has the structure of a riddle, but I don't know the answer so I don't think that the Riddles.SE would be good either.

Riddles.SE doesn't exist in the first place. It is still in Area 51 in the first or second stage of trying to make it a beta (the third is actually private beta). So since it has some computer programming in it, you could narrow it down to:

- Code Review
- Stack Overflow
- Programming Puzzles and Code Golf

Since you have no idea what to do, you should eliminate Code Review and Stack Overflow since a well-recieved question will need example code of some type to show that you tackled the problem in the first place. That leaves with: Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.

This should be the site you post your question on since it has a structure of a riddle (do not try Puzzling.SE). You can simply ask your question and add the desired results. Naturally, the best answer uses the least bytes...

So try this site: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mathematics.SE is not only for professional math, in fact, the description says: For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields. MathOverflow is only for professional research level maths.